# fast-serialization android studio gradle error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-proguard

I am using [this](https://github.com/RuedigerMoeller/fast-serialization) library for my mobile application, but when I try to create a signed APK with ProGuard enabled (release configuration) it gives me thousands of errors like these:

```
Warning:javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.connect.AttachingConnector
Warning:javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.connect.Connector$Argument
Warning:javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.connect.AttachingConnector
Warning:javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.VirtualMachine
Warning:javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.Bootstrap
Warning:javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.VirtualMachineManager
Warning:javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.connect.Connector
Warning:javassist.util.HotSwapper: can't find referenced class com.sun.jdi.request.EventRequestManager
```

I've tried the following proguard rules

```
-dontwarn com.**
-dontwarn sun.**
-dontwarn java.**
-keep class com.** { *; }
-keep class sun.** { *; }
-keep class java.** { *; }
```

But this just resulted in my signed APK generating forever and never finishing. What did I forget to configure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it using the following proguard rules

```
-dontwarn com.**
-dontwarn sun.**
-dontwarn java.**
-keep class com.** { *; }
-keep class sun.** { *; }
-keep class java.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class sun.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class java.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.** { *; }
```

Although I do not understand why I need `-keepclassmembers` for the gradle build to complete.